# Missing + button on in App Purchases localizations

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I want to add a new localization for my app in App Store Connect but the <kbd>+</kbd> button is missing. What am I doing wrong?

[image: IAP localizations]

Comment: Is this the "App Information" page? [My interface](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aheze/DeveloperAssets/master/Screen%20Shot%202021-03-10%20at%201.33.23%20PM.png) is a bit different

Comment: Wait, is this for in-app purchases? It does seem to be missing...

Comment: In appstoreconnect, my App on the in App Purchase page. The + button was there, I added the English localisations.. but now he is gone :-(

Comment: Got it. You will most likely need to create a new version first. Go to the left side of the screen, and click the + button.

Comment: You are right. But every time i want to add a new localisation i need a new IAP? Each IAP comes with a unique product id. Sounds very complicated...

Comment: No, just a new app version.

Comment: I have a new version waiting for review. If this version is approved i can add a new localisation, right? Than i have to wait a little bit and try again...

Comment: In the new version, are you able to change the localization settings?

Comment: Not actually, but maybe if the review is done? I’ll waiting for the review

Comment: @aheze: You are right. Review is done an + button is back again. Weird but ok for me :-)